# What does "size of NDEF messages" mean in the given context below?

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, ndef

I am currently working on NXP's NTag213 and NTag215 and while I was going through the document, it confused me. Let me explain

For NTag213, it has 45 pages in total, each with 4 bytes so a total of 180 bytes. Out of these 180 bytes(45 pages), 36 bytes(9 pages) are used for the serial number, CC, static and dynamic lock bytes, configuration bytes, password bytes and RFU. The remaining 144 bytes are user memory.

Similarly For NTag215, it has 135 pages in total, each with 4 bytes so a total of 540 bytes. Out of these 540 bytes(135 pages), 36 bytes(9 pages) are used for the serial number, CC, static and dynamic lock bytes, configuration bytes, password bytes and RFU. The remaining 504 bytes are user memory.

Now in the document, I found the below statement
[image: Snapshot from document]

it states that byte 2 of CC defines the available memory size for NDEF messages. What does that mean?

Moreover, for NTag 213 we see NDEF memory size as 144 bytes equivalent to user memory size but with NTag215, NDEf memory size is 496 and its not eqivalent to user memory size of 504 bytes. Please explain what am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It specifies "on delivery", from [table 6 in section 8.5.6 here](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf) we can see that pages 4 + 5 are populated on delivery even though they are part of the user memory. This would equate to the 8 bytes missing.